# Can't fix "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" in Python

Tags: python, random

I need help fixing the error. Here is my code:

```
import random
def game():
        capitals={"England":"London","France":"Paris","Belgiom":"Brussels",\
                  "Canada":"Ottawa","China":"Beijing","Cyprus":"Nicosia",\
                  "Cuba":"Havana","Egypt":"Cairo","Greece":"Athens",\
                  "Ireland":"Dublin","Italy":"Rome","a":"A","B":"B"}

    wrong=[]
    right=[]

    incorrect_answers = False

    while len(capitals)>0:
        pick = random.choice(list(capitals.keys()))
        correct_answer = capitals.get(pick)
        print ("What is the capital city of" + pick + "?")
        answer = input("Your answer: ")
        if answer.lower() == correct_answer.lower():
            print ("That's Correct!\n")
            del capitals[pick]
            right.append(pick)
        else:
            print ("That's Incorrect.\n")
            print ("The correct answer is" + correct_answer + "\n")
            wrong.append(pick)
            incorrect_answers = True
            del capitals[pick]


    print ("You got  ",len(right), "/", len(wrong))
    top = len(right)
    bottom = len(wrong)
    perc = float((top / bottom) * 100)
    print(perc)    

    if incorrect_answers:
        print ("Here are the ones that you may want to brush up on:\n")
        for each in wrong:
            print (each)
    else:
        print ("Perfect!")

def help():
        print("do you neeeded efhdufghaf dfgjn")

while True:
    input = input("what do you want to do? help or play?")
    if input == "help":
        help()
        break
    if input == "play":
        print("you want to play")
        game()
        break
```

Comment: Provide the traceback so we know where the error is.

Comment: The rows between `Traceback (most recent call last):` to `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` that show up in an error message are a veritable goldmine when debugging, pointing to which area of the code is causing problems etc.  You should make sure you have that at the end on pretty much every question.

Comment: I have fixed it now. But thanks anyway. This is my first post so don't know all the rules...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't do this

```
input = input("what do you want to do? help or play?")
```

You are shadowing the function `input` with your variable. Change the name of your variable to something else.